# Is it possible to run [some] Firebase JS libraries without IndexedDB API?

Tags: javascript, firebase, indexeddb

Some Firebase JS SDK libraries (e.g. firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config, firebase-performance) seem to require IndexedDB API to initialize. Is it possible to run these libraries and have the IndexedDB API disabled (i.e. for browsers without IndexedDB support)?

I've started to look through the Firebase JS SDK code as well, but wanted to see if anyone has a quick answer.

Cheers